# Bat file termination

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Consider two **bat** files.

#### outer.bat

```
echo Before
inner.bat
echo After
```

#### inner.bat

```
echo Inner
goto :eof
```

When I execute *outer.bat* "After" is not echoed. So *"goto :eof"* in the inner script terminates the outer script.

Can I rewrite *outer.bat* to continue execution after calling *inner.bat* without modifying *inner.bat*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch files have a single execution context. When you nest batchfile calls like that, the nested file completely replaces the outer/parent batch file's context. There's no record saying that there was a parent batch file, so you simply return to the prompt when the inner file completes.

To be able to return to the outer batch file, you have to do

```
 echo Before
 call inner.bat
 echo After
```