# Batch file doesn't run the next command after 'gem install'

Tags: batch-file, rubygems

I made a batch file trying to setup rake/albacore environment on windows:

```
@echo off

echo Setting up rake environment for building

echo Installing Bundler
gem install bundler

echo Bundle Installing gems
bundle install
```

When I run this batch file (either double click or run inside a cmd window), only the first gem command is executed. The 'bundle install' is never called. Here is the output:

```
C:\>InstallGems.bat
Setting up rake environment for building
Installing Bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.2.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.2.1...

C:\>
```

I have added 'pause' after the first 'gem install' command and it seems the 'pause' is never executed either.

Any idea?

Comment: It is possible that Gem itself is a batch-file, or that the script is somehow aborting due to a error and not telling you about the error.

Answer (score 22):

Ahh, I figured it out: just add 'call' before each command.

```
@echo off

echo Setting up rake environment for building

echo Installing Bundler
call gem install bundler

echo Bundle Installing gems
call bundle install
```

Comment: seems gem is a batchfile itself. due to the way dos previously operated, for backwards compatibility, this behaviour is by design: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638705/why-does-calling-a-nested-batch-file-without-prepending-call-to-the-line-exit