# msdeploy command throwing error when executed from .bat file

Tags: batch-file, iis, msdeploy

Following is my `msdeploy` command to copy files from one server to another (`server1` to `server2`) successfully:

```
MSDeploy.exe -source:contentPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist",computerName="https://server1:8172/MSDeploy.axd",username="administrator",password="XXXXXXXXX",authtype="Basic" -allowUntrusted -dest:contentPath='C:\Builds\dist',computerName="https://server2:8172/MSDeploy.axd",username="administrator",password="XXXXXXXXXX",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted
```

I have one more similar command exactly as above to transfer files between `server3` and `server4` as well which is working successfully from command prompt. Whereas when i put one of these commands or both in a `.bat` file, getting the following error:

[image]

Below is the exact content of my batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

CD C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3

MSDeploy.exe -source:contentPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist",computerName="https://server1:8172/MSDeploy.axd",username="administrator",password="XXXXXXXXX",authtype="Basic" -allowUntrusted -dest:contentPath='C:\Builds\dist',computerName="https://server2:8172/MSDeploy.axd",username="administrator",password="XXXXXXXXXX",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted

MSDeploy.exe -source:contentPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist",computerName="https://server3:8172/MSDeploy.axd",username="administrator",password="XXXXXXXXX",authtype="Basic" -allowUntrusted -dest:contentPath='C:\Builds\dist',computerName="https://server4:8172/MSDeploy.axd",username="administrator",password="XXXXXXXXXX",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted
```

I tried running as an administrator , still the same problem. To my surprise the exact same commands with some other servers are working fine from the .bat file as well.

Comment: Did you intend to use single quotes for 'C:\Builds\dist'  ?

Comment: No, double quotes is the right way as far as I know

Comment: `CD C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3` needs `"`s around the directory name as it contains spaces.

Comment: tried adding ", made no difference as well. Indeed the same command without " is working fine for other servers in a different bat file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing the batch file with `cmd /c` is working. Usually `cmd /c` needs to be used to return control to the bat file even though there are fatal errors. Don't know the exact reason why only this works because there are no fatal errors in my case.

check this for more information [A .bat File, "Call" or Not to "Call", That is the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731877/a-bat-file-call-or-not-to-call-that-is-the)