# Is it possible to run two batch files from Jenkins?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I have the following case. In jenkins I have one build which is running on different envoironments. That's why I have build with parameters with two options `PROD/TEST`. The build is invoking shell script with parameter `PROD` or `TEST`.

Here is example of the script `A` which jenkins is invoking:

```
if %1%==TEST(
start F:\test.bat
 )
```

The script `A` itself is invoking another script - `B`.

Here is example of script `B`:

```
copy test.xt copyFolder\
```

The problem is that Jenkins only invoking the first script - `A` - and the second script `B` doesn't run.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `if /I "%~1"=="TEST" (call "F:\test.bat")`?

Comment: it works with like this

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [`call`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php) the batch file, not `start` it because it creates a new `cmd.exe` instance, so it can run a called batch file asynchronously (as mentioned by jeb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731933)):

```bat
if "%~1" == "TEST" (
    call F:\test.bat
)
```

Here, I want to note some things:

- `%1%` will be interpreted as the **first argument of the batch file** *(if any)* and an extra **percent-sign (`%`)**. You probably wanted here the first argument, so I have replaced `%1%` with `%1`. If it is not this what you wanted, then replace it with your variable name, but remember that it should not start with a number!
- `%1` was replaced by `%~1` and quoted because:

  - `%~1` means the first argument without *any* surrounding quotes.
  - Quoting the values in an `if` statement is always the best practice, but if there were quotes, the comparison would fail.
- Added a space between `==`, just to make the code clearer.

For an one-liner, see [aschipfl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864053/is-it-possible-to-run-two-batch-files-from-jenkins#comment96498792_54864053), it is:

```bat
if /I "%~1"=="TEST" (call "F:\test.bat")
```

See `call /?` and `if /?` in cmd for more information about how these commands work.