# .less compilation in batch for-loop ends batch script prematurely

Tags: css, batch-file, less

I'm new to batch, but I figured out it would be a good way to compile the [.less](http://lesscss.org) files for my website into .css before deploying it.

Unfortunately, after I use a `for` loop in a batch file to find all of my .less files and compile them into their .css equivalents, my script stops execution even though I have more commands after the `for` loop.

My batch script contains the following:

```
@echo off
rmdir c:\code\releaseDirectory /s /q
echo d | xcopy /d c:\code\devDirectory c:\code\releaseDirectory /s
cd c:\code\releaseDirectory
for /r %%i in (*.less) do echo %%i
for /r %%i in (*.less) do lessc -x %%i > %%~pi%%~ni.css
echo reached the end of the batch script!
```

When I run this, the output shows all of the .less compiling happening, but the "reached the end of the batch script!" string never get displayed and thus, and any actions I want to take after the .less compilation never happen.

Why isn't any script after the less compilation in the `for` loop being executed?

Comment: Related: *[Why does only the first line of this Windows batch file execute but all three lines execute in a command shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036754)*

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and had to change `lessc` to `call lessc` and then my script stopped ending prematurely. Here is a SO link that lead me to try it: [Why does calling a nested batch file without prepending "call" to the line exit the parent batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638705/why-does-calling-a-nested-batch-file-without-prepending-call-to-the-line-exit) Basically it says that you need to use `call` when executing nested batch files so that control will be returned to the parent file when the sub-file is finished executing.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a `lessc.bat` in your path?

If so, you need to `CALL lessc...`

---

Is there an "odd" filename? being processed?

Perhaps ...do **ECHO %%i&** lessc -x %%i > %%~pi%%~ni.css

may reveal more...

Comment: Sorry, no, lessc is the .Less compiler used to compile the .less files into .css files.  http://lesscss.org/#usage

Comment: After adding in the extra echo and redirecting the batch script to a .txt file, the output for each line of the for-loop looked like `c:\Code\releaseDirectory>echo c:\Code\releaseDirectory\styles\common.less   & lessc -x c:\Code\releaseDirectory\styles\common.less  1>\Code\releaseDirectory\styles\common.css 
c:\Code\releaseDirectory\styles\common.less`  except for the very first iteration of the for loop, which only output `c:\Code\releaseDirectory\styles\about.less`.  Would the first iteration only showing that indicate an error of some sort?

Comment: More than likely. I'd suggest you try changing to cd c:\code\releaseDirectory and try `lessc -x c:\Code\releaseDirectory\styles\about.less > \Code\releaseDirectory\styles\about.css` from the prompt and see what happens. Maybe actually remove the `>...` part and just let the output appear on the screen. **BTW** `%%~pni.css` will work just as well as `%%~pi%%~ni`

Comment: The output appears as expected, so it doesn't appear as though there's anything wrong with the about.less file.  Any other ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
for /r %%i in (*.less) do lessc.exe -x "%%~i" "%%~dpni.css"
...
```

Comment: Think it is normally "lessc.cmd" not "lessc.exe" in windows. However, for /r %%i in (*.less) do lessc -x "%%~i" "%%~dpni.css" will work.