# Jython command terminating batch scripts

Tags: python, cmd, jython

In a directory I have three files.

- **test.py**, containing `print "Hello World"`
- **python_runner.bat**, containing

  - `python test.py
    PAUSE`
- **jython_runner.bat**, containing

  - `jython test.py 
    PAUSE`

The python_runner.bat works as expected, but running Jython_runner.bat causes the PAUSE command to be skipped!

Why is Jython causing the batch script to be prematurely terminated?

(NOTE: I am using Jython2.7b4, I haven't tried with Jython 2.5)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does calling a nested batch file without prepending "call" to the line exit the parent batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638705/why-does-calling-a-nested-batch-file-without-prepending-call-to-the-line-exit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the jython command is a batch script then the pause and any thing after this will not be executed.

try `call`

```
call jython test.py
```

What is the outcome?

Comment: The Jython command does resolve to a batch script! Using `call` makes everything work properly. I didn't know about this strange batch-scripts-calling-batch-scripts behavior... very odd

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638705/why-does-calling-a-nested-batch-file-without-prepending-call-to-the-line-exit